# Flex 3 ColumnChart: dynamically changing the column colors

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

When using a ColumnChart created in Flex 3, how can I to change the fill color of columns that meet a certain criteria?

Example:  I have 8 columns representing agreement percentages between groups of people and want to change the fill color (or otherwise highlight) of all the columns that have over 80% agreement.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [documentation on per-item fills](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_displayingdata_09.html).